# Labels for tooltips on primefaces barchartseries

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I have tried to search both the forum and Google extensively, but I have problems understanding how I should make this work:

PrimeFaces6

I have a BarchartModel based on the tutorial in the ShowCase:
CODE: SELECT ALL
private BarChartModel initStatusBarChart() {
        BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();

```
    ChartSeries statusMessages = new ChartSeries();
    statusMessages.setLabel("Label"));
    statusMessages.set("Some String 1", list1.size());
    statusMessages.set("Some String 2", list2.size());


    model.addSeries(statusMessages);
    return model;
}
```

The issue is that on render, I get tooltips the format of

"1, 515" and "2, 432", where 515 and 432 are the sizes of list1 and list2, respectively.

How can I replace 1 and 2 with the values "Some String" 1 and 2 ? Have tried extending highlighter and using dataTipFormat, with no success.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem using the datatip editor of the chart model (with Primefaces 6.1, by the way). I used this for a stacked bar chart.
I needed to apply this solution at two places: the backing bean and the JSF page.

In the backing bean I had to set a JavaScript function name this way:

```
barModel.setDatatipEditor("chartDatatipEditor");
```

I tried to set it using the corresponding tag attribute in the JSF page but to no effect.

In the JSF I inserted this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chartDatatipEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
  //console.log('chartDatatipEditor: '+str+" - "+seriesIndex+" - "+pointIndex);
  var point = seriesIndex+','+pointIndex;
  #{bean.datatipsJs}
}
</script>
```

This JS function gets the chart coordinates as parameters. I concat them so that the following JS code gets easier. 
*seriesIndex* is the index of the chart series. *pointIndex* is the index on the X scale of the diagram.

To find out what are the correct values for your chart you can uncomment the *console.log* line above.

The inserted JS code is constructed in the backing bean this way:

```
private Map<String, String> chartDatatips;

public String getDatatipsJs() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("switch ( point ) {\n");
    for (String point : chartDatatips.keySet()) {
        sb.append("case '").append(point).append("': return '").append(chartDatatips.get(point)).append("'; break;\n");
    }
    sb.append("default: return 'Unknown point'; break; }");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The map *chartDatatips* has the coordinate point as key (e.g., "2,1") and the tooltip as value.

During the chart setup you obviously have to fill this map with useful details ;-)

Like this:

```
chartDatatips.put("2,5", "Label ...");
...
```

Hope this helps, if you didn't already solved this.

~Alex

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alex's answer I have come up with this. Only requiring javascript - it displays the label and value:

In the backing bean, set a JavaScript function name this way:

```
barModel.setDatatipEditor("chartDatatipEditor");
```

In the HTML file:

```
function chartDatatipEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
    return plot.series[seriesIndex].label + ' - ' + plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex];
}
```